# If there were no continent that spanning between the North and South Hemispheres would there be a Circum-equatorial Current?

Tags: ocean-currents

Let's just imagine that there are no continents that span the equator like Africa and South America and also no large Equatorial Islands like those in Indonesian archipelago.

So that between latitude 10 north and 10 south there are no substantial landmasses.

Holding Earth's other physical parameters constant would there be a circum-equatorial current like Antarctic Circumpolar Current?

Would it be stronger/faster than the current Pacific Equatorial Current? How strong would it be?

Could a wooden sail ship cross the current from North to sail to South?

This is the first part of the question. The second part of question would be to ask the effect of a continous equatorial current on the world climate.

Comment: Rather a [World Building](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) question. Questions about ocean currents in e.g. Tethys Ocean, would have been a more interesting topic for experts.

Comment: Oh... Then it should be migrated then?

Comment: I think you'll attract more relevant answers for your question there. However, ocean currents have been very different in the past, maybe you can edit your question to actually be about an ocean that existed, like Tethys or Panthalassa. There are also people here that knows a lot about the actual currents today and might explain the mechanisms.

Comment: You can start by looking at the paleo-oceanographic evidence of the circulation before the appearance of the Isthmus of Panama. For instance: http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v393/n6686/abs/393673a0.html

Comment: If you want your question migrated to worldbuilding, flag iit "in need of  moderator attention" and request migration or ping me in the comments here and I'll move it for you.

Comment: Well... I mostly interested in how strong the current will be... The NEC was 50 cm/s and SEC was 1 m/s... So I wonder how much speed was a CEC.... and how it will affect ship that passed through it... (is there any ship board in stackexchange?)

Comment: @aretxabaleta full pdf of Nature article: http://shadow.eas.gatech.edu/~jean/paleo/Haug_1998.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Even though that this is something I asked back 3 month ago It surprising to see that there is someone replying to it.